# How to determine which pair of pseudo tty ports are connected to each other in bash

Tags: bash, shell, pty, socat

I have a pair of linux C programs that use pseudo terminals `/dev/pts/*` to communicate to each other. The pty on which can communicate is passed as command line argument to these programs.

I can create a pair of pty devices using socat as follows:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

The output of above gives as:

```
2018/07/05 17:56:54 socat[58319] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2018/07/05 17:56:54 socat[58319] N PTY is /dev/pts/3
2018/07/05 17:56:54 socat[58319] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [7,7] and [9,9]
```

how can I extract the pty nodes, `/dev/pts/*` from `socat`'s output and pass to my application via command line in a shell script:

```
$./test_pty_app /dev/pts/1 & 
$./test_pty_app /dev/pts/2 &
```

I saw a similar question that can do this in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847650/how-to-determine-which-pair-of-pseudo-tty-ports-are-connected-to-each-other)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It looks like you'll have to use a file if `socat` must be backgrounded.

```
( socat ... 2>&1 | grep -Eo "/dev/pts/\d+" > /tmp/a ) &
portA=$(head -n 1 /tmp/a)
portB=$(tail -n 1 /tmp/a)
```

**Original Answer**

@jeremysprofile 's answer is probably more sensible but, just for fun, you could do either of these also:

```
socat ... | grep -Eo "/dev/pts/\d+" | { read portA; read portB; }
```

Or, using bash's *"process substitution"*, you could do:

```
{ read portA; read portB; } < <(socat ... | grep -Eo "/dev/pts/\d+")
```

Then you would do this after either of them:

```
./test_pty_app $portA &
./test_pty_app $portB &
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. On passing portA and portB values to the app and printing them (since echoing did not print them) I get NULL values. Seems portA and portB are not assigned the pty node values. Also `socat` needs to run in background in order for the bash to run again, otherwise it waits for a sigterm to terminate and then bash gets running again.

Comment: `grep` does not understand `\d+`, you have to use `[0-9]\+` instead.

Comment: It is also necessary to pass `--line-buffered` to `grep`. Else nothing is written in `/tmp/a`.

Comment: There is also a possible race between the moment when `grep` writes `/tmp/a` and the moment when you read `/tmp/a`

Answer (score 2):

```
 arr=($(socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1 | grep -oh "/dev/pts/\w*"))
```

now `"${arr[0]}"` and `"${arr[1]}"` are your two tty ports.

`grep -oh` prints out only the pattern it matches, nothing else. `/dev/pts/\w* matches only something starting with /dev/pts/ and then any number of alphanumeric (or _) characters, which basically means "until the end of the word".

Comment: Thank you for the response. This does not work. I get an error as: `command substitution: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token '|' `.

I tried with the following too it does not work:
 `arr=($(socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1 | grep -oh "/dev/pts/\w* &")) `

Comment: @YusufHusainy, is `socat`'s output via stderr?

Comment: Yes I believe so since, without the stderr redirection to stdout, `grep` was not getting it;s input to work on

Comment: Thank you again jeremy. The edited answer still does not work. Since i need socat to run in background, otherwise the bash script will not process unless I terminate socat using sigterm

Comment: What does this do: `{arr=($(socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1 | grep -oh "/dev/pts/\w*"))}  &` ?

Comment: It gives a syntax error like so:
`syntax error near unexpected token $(socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1 | grep -oh "/dev/pts/\w*")`

Comment: An interesting thing observered is that the following works without assigning to array:
`socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1 | grep -oh "/dev/pts/\w*" &`.

It prints out the pty nodes, then need to assign in to array as well as have it run in the background

Comment: @YusufHusainy, sorry, this is out of my depth. I do not know how you could do this. best of luck.